# How to retrieve rows from a csv file using a tag string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file contains data like this:

I have write down a code which is able to retrieve the rows  which contains  "Active" at second column "outcome":

**Data:**

```
No,Outcome,target,result
1,Active,PGS2,positive
2,inactive,IM2,negative
3,inactive,IGI,positive
4,Active,IIL,positive
5,Active,P53,negative
```

**Code:**

```
new_file  = open(my_file)
lines  = new_file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "Active" in line:
        print line,
```

**Outcome:**

```
No,Outcome,target,result
1,Active,PGS2,positive
4,Active,IIL,positive
5,Active,P53,negative
```

How can i write down this code using pandas library so that i can make this code shorter if i am using pandas functionality after retrieving the rows.

Also this code is not suitable when you have "Active"  key word same where else in yor row because that can retrieve a false row. I found after previewing some posts that "pandas" is very suitable library for CSV Handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just filter this aftewards, it will be faster than parsing line by line. Just do this:

```
In [172]:

df[df['Outcome']=='Active']
Out[172]:
   No Outcome target    result
0   1  Active   PGS2  positive
3   4  Active    IIL  positive
4   5  Active    P53  negative
```

Comment: hey thank you again is there any function like pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)" for column also because same problem is arising in case of columns i tried pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None) but its not working

Comment: Do you mean `max_colwidth`? there is a list of options in an answer I gave previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293536/list-of-pandas-options/21293562#21293562

Comment: thanks you again "pd.set_option('display.line_width',2000)" worked for me