# ipython notebook firefox scrollbar

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas DataFrame with more than 70 columns.
When I produce a calculation on it, firefox (on windows) has the DataFrame printed in a greater space than the window is allotted for it. I would like the scrollbar to fit inside the ipython window allotted for it. Is there any clean way to handle this?

It can be recreated in firefox using this code in an ipython notebook window.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 20))
df.tail()
```

Comment: What exactly is a dataframe? Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: yes, I added it for clarity

Comment: And your data is printed once you do a calculation? or do you `print` the result? I'd guess the previous one is specified by `DataFrame.__repr__` and the second one by `DataFrame.__str__`? But I'm no Panda expert at all...

Comment: You can fix the max col width and the max number of columns to display, alternatively you can do `to_html()`. So what exactly is it you want to restrict the max width displayed? You can change this using `pd.set_option('display.max_width, some_val)` and also `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth, some_val)`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293536/list-of-pandas-options-for-method-set-option/21293562#21293562) for a list of options

Comment: I do not want to limit the columns out.  I want ipython notebook window for out to contain the entire dataframe

Comment: then up the limit, if you set to -1 then there will be no restriction for max width and max col width

Comment: right, but I do not think it's a pandas issue

Comment: It looks like a firefox & ipython interaction problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

**Problem description with images**

While using the following options.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

The whole dataframe was printed, but I wasn't able to scroll to the columns on the right. However, I was able to make the window wider to see more columns. But of course, there is a limit to this.

[image]

**Solutions**

In my case, the problem was in the interaction of JupyterLab and Firefox.

So I found two solutions:

**1. Solution**: Use a different browser.

In my case e.g. Chrome worked as expected.

**2. Solution**: Downgrade Jupyterlab to version 3.6.5 (4.0.2 before)

```
pip install jupyterlab==3.6.5
```

I chose the downgrade:
[image]